# Splitting Long integer (ID field) into sub fields using R

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector if ID's which i need to split into sub fields. The length of the subfields are constant which I hope will make things straightforward. Currently the ID field looks like this:

```
ID
0100001000
0100002000
0100003000
0100004000
0100005000
0100006000
0100007000
0100008000
0100009000
0100010000
```

and I need to split it into sub ID fields like so:

```
06  00546   000
12  00387   000
21  02437   000
01  06419   000
17  03892   000
17  00010   000
13  02199   000
17  00706   000
05  03358   000
05  03892   000
```

These values are just examples of format, not content ie the example above just shows that i need to take a string of xxxxxxxxxx and turn it into xx xxxxx xxx please ignore the values.

I'm looking for a solution I can implement in R and I have the feeling I need to be using regular expressions for this but need a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: i'm wondering how `0100001000` was splitted into `06  00546   000`

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247045/chopping-a-string-into-a-vector-of-fixed-width-character-elements

Comment: @AvinashRaj It wasn't this is just an example of format, not content

Comment: @ConnorM You could use `read.fwf` and specify the widths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, 'ID', into=c('ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'), '(.{2})(.{5})(.{3})')
#    ID1   ID2 ID3
# 1   01 00001 000
# 2   01 00002 000
# 3   01 00003 000
# 4   01 00004 000
# 5   01 00005 000
# 6   01 00006 000
# 7   01 00007 000
# 8   01 00008 000
# 9   01 00009 000
#10   01 00010 000
```

Or read the file using `read.fwf` with specified `widths`.

```
read.fwf('file.txt', widths=c(2,5,3), skip=1, #skip to remove the ID row
             header=FALSE,colClasses=rep('character',3))
#   V1    V2  V3
#1  01 00001 000
#2  01 00002 000
#3  01 00003 000
#4  01 00004 000
#5  01 00005 000
#6  01 00006 000
#7  01 00007 000
#8  01 00008 000
#9  01 00009 000
#10 01 00010 000
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks, I was about to make that correction.

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this also.

```
> df <- data.frame(ID=c("0100001000", "0100002000", "0100003000"))
> df
          ID
1 0100001000
2 0100002000
3 0100003000
> as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, regmatches(df$ID, gregexpr("^\\d{2}|(?<=^\\d{2})\\d{5}|\\d{3}$", df$ID,perl=T))))
  V1    V2  V3
1 01 00001 000
2 01 00002 000
3 01 00003 000
```

**OR**

```
> library(stringi)
> as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, stri_split(as.character(df$ID), regex="(?<=^\\d{2})|(?=\\d{3}$)")))
  V1    V2  V3
1 01 00001 000
2 01 00002 000
3 01 00003 000
```

Comment: i can't do this through `strsplit` but `stri_split` does the job.

Comment: it's ok, no prob.. :-)