# Splitting a string into fixed-size chunks

Tags: r, string

This seems like a really simple task, but I can't find a good solution in base R. I have a character string with 2N characters. How do I split this into a character vector of length N, with each element being a 2-character string?

I could use something like `substr` with `Vectorize`:

```
vss <- Vectorize(substr, c("start", "stop"))
ch <- paste(rep("a", 1e6), collapse="")
vss(ch, seq(1, nchar(ch), by=2), seq(2, nchar(ch), by=2))
```

but this is really slow for long strings (O(N^2) I believe).

Comment: Use `substring` which is vectorized also in `first` and `last`.

Comment: That works, but it has the same problem as `Vectorize(substr)` does, ie O(N^2) runtime. It also makes N/2 copies of the initial string so it's also O(N^2) memory!

Comment: If the chars in your string are ASCII (or at least you don't have multibyte chars), you could try `apply(matrix(charToRaw(ch),nrow=2),2,rawToChar)` which appears to be much faster than `substring`, and scale mostly linearly.

Comment: GSee's answer runs v. fast http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247045/chopping-a-string-into-a-vector-of-fixed-width-character-elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want speed, [`Rcpp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) is always a good choice:

```
library(Rcpp);
cppFunction('
    List strsplitN(std::vector<std::string> v, int N ) {
        if (N < 1) throw std::invalid_argument("N must be >= 1.");
        List res(v.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
            int num = v[i].size()/N + (v[i].size()%N == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            std::vector<std::string> resCur(num,std::string(N,0));
            for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j) resCur[j].assign(v[i].substr(j*N,N));
            res[i] = resCur;
        }
        return res;
    }
');

ch <- paste(rep('a',1e6),collapse='');
system.time({ res <- strsplitN(ch,2L); });
##    user  system elapsed
##   0.109   0.015   0.121
head(res[[1L]]); tail(res[[1L]]);
## [1] "aa" "aa" "aa" "aa" "aa" "aa"
## [1] "aa" "aa" "aa" "aa" "aa" "aa"
length(res[[1L]]);
## [1] 500000
```

---

Useful reference: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/strings_with_rcpp/.

---

More demos:

```
strsplitN(c('abcd','efgh'),2L);
## [[1]]
## [1] "ab" "cd"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "ef" "gh"
##
strsplitN(c('abcd','efgh'),3L);
## [[1]]
## [1] "abc" "d"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "efg" "h"
##
strsplitN(c('abcd','efgh'),1L);
## [[1]]
## [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "e" "f" "g" "h"
##
strsplitN(c('abcd','efgh'),5L);
## [[1]]
## [1] "abcd"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "efgh"
##
strsplitN(character(),5L);
## list()
strsplitN(c('abcd','efgh'),0L);
## Error: N must be >= 1.
```

---

There are two important caveats with the above implementation:

**1:** It doesn't handle `NA`s correctly. Rcpp seems to stringify to `'NA'` when it's forced to come up with a `std::string`. You can easily solve this in Rland with a wrapper that replaces the offending list components with a true `NA`.

```
x <- c('a',NA); strsplitN(x,1L);
## [[1]]
## [1] "a"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "N" "A"
##
x <- c('a',NA); ifelse(is.na(x),NA,strsplitN(x,1L));
## [[1]]
## [1] "a"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] NA
##
```

**2:** It doesn't handle multibyte characters correctly. This is a tougher problem, and would require a rewrite of the core function implementation to use a Unicode-aware traversal. Fixing this problem would also incur a significant performance penalty, since you wouldn't be able to preallocate each vector in one shot prior to the assignment loop.

```
strsplitN('aΩ',1L);
## [[1]]
## [1] "a"    "\xce" "\xa9"
##
strsplit('aΩ','');
## [[1]]
## [1] "a" "Ω"
##
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Would you mind if I make a package on GitHub using this Funktion? Naturally, I'll credit you in the DESCRIPTION. I need this in a script that will run several times a day. A package would save me compiling.

Comment: You're very welcome. Sure, go right ahead.

Comment: The package can be found here: https://github.com/BerriJ/strsplit.fix It really just contains you function and no docs (yet). Maybe its also useful for someone else :)

Comment: What about a function that split a character in the following way: `"My cat"` in chunks of 3 -> `"My ", "y  c", " ca", "cat"`