# R, split string to pairs of character

Tags: r

How to split string in R in following way ?  Look at example, please

```
example:
```

`c("ex", "xa", "am", "mp", "pl", "le")` ?

Comment: Maybe also somewhat related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247045/chopping-a-string-into-a-vector-of-fixed-width-character-elements

Answer (score 13):

```
x = "example"
substring(x, first = 1:(nchar(x) - 1), last = 2:nchar(x))
# [1] "ex" "xa" "am" "mp" "pl" "le"
```

You could, of course, wrap it into a function, maybe omit non-letters (I don't know if the colon was supposed to be part of your string or not), etc.

To do this to a vector of strings, you can use it as an anonymous function with `lapply`:

```
lapply(month.name, function(x) substring(x, first = 1:(nchar(x) - 1), last = 2:nchar(x)))
# [[1]]
# [1] "Ja" "an" "nu" "ua" "ar" "ry"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Fe" "eb" "br" "ru" "ua" "ar" "ry"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "Ma" "ar" "rc" "ch"
# ...
```

Or make it into a named function and use it by name. This would make sense if you'll use it somewhat frequently.

```
str_split_pairs = function(x) {
    substring(x, first = 1:(nchar(x) - 1), last = 2:nchar(x))
}

lapply(month.name, str_split_pairs)
## same result as above
```

Comment: Ok, I have a vector of strings (character). How to get from it vector of such pairs ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option (though it's slower than @Gregor's answer):

```
x=c("example", "stackoverflow", "programming")

lapply(x, function(i) {
  i = unlist(strsplit(i,""))
  paste0(i, lead(i))[-length(i)]
})
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "ex" "xa" "am" "mp" "pl" "le"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "st" "ta" "ac" "ck" "ko" "ov" "ve" "er" "rf" "fl" "lo" "ow"
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "pr" "ro" "og" "gr" "ra" "am" "mm" "mi" "in" "ng"
> ```