# Split string every n characters new column

Tags: r, substring, gsub, stringr

Suppose I have a data frame like this with a string vector, var2

```
var1  var2
1     abcdefghi 
2     abcdefghijklmnop
3     abc 
4     abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

What is the most efficient way to split var2 every n characters into new columns until the end of each string,

e.g if every 4 characters, the output would like look like this:

```
var1  var2                  new_var1  new_var2 new_var3  new_var4  new_var5
1     abcdefghi             abcd      efgh     i 
2     abcdefghijklmnop      abcd      efgh     ijkl      mnop 
3     abc                   abc
4     abcdefghijklmnopqrst  abcd      efgh     ijkl      mnop      qrst
```

stringr package? Using "str_split_fixed"

Or Using regular expressions:

```
gsub("(.{4})", "\\1 ", "abcdefghi")
```

Capacity to create new columns that go to new_var_n depending on  length of var2, which could be 10000 characters for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can try `read.fwf` in base R. No special package is needed:

```
tmp <- read.fwf(
    textConnection(dtf$var2),
    widths = rep(4, ceiling(max(nchar(dtf$var2) / 4))),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cbind(dtf, tmp)

#   var1                 var2   V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
# 1    1            abcdefghi abcd efgh    i <NA> <NA>
# 2    2     abcdefghijklmnop abcd efgh ijkl mnop <NA>
# 3    3                  abc  abc <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 4    4 abcdefghijklmnopqrst abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one option with `data.table` and a helper function `fixed_split` that I took from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38483821/8583393) and slightly modified (it uses `tstrsplit` instead of `strsplit`).

```
library(data.table)
fixed_split <- function(text, n) {
  data.table::tstrsplit(text, paste0("(?<=.{",n,"})"), perl=TRUE)
}
```

Define `n`, the number of characters and `new_vars`, the number of columns to add first

```
n <- 4
new_vars <- ceiling(max(nchar(df$var2)) / n)

setDT(df)[, paste0("new_var", seq_len(new_vars)) := fixed_split(var2, n = n)][]
#   var1                 var2 new_var1 new_var2 new_var3 new_var4 new_var5
#1:    1            abcdefghi     abcd     efgh        i     <NA>     <NA>
#2:    2     abcdefghijklmnop     abcd     efgh     ijkl     mnop     <NA>
#3:    3                  abc      abc     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
#4:    4 abcdefghijklmnopqrst     abcd     efgh     ijkl     mnop     qrst
```

Comment: do you have any idea if I have a list like this - [1] "a" "b" "c" "d", how can I combine them into "ab", "cd". basically I used str_split("abcd", "") and got stuck

Comment: @Hardikgupta You might consider to use `fixed_split("abcd", 2)` (as defined above) instead of `str_split`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative using `strsplit` and `matrix` coercion

```
str_split_n <- function(x, n = 4) {
    sapply(x, function(ss) {
        nc <- nchar(as.character(ss))
        apply(matrix(replace(
            rep("", n * ceiling(nc / n)), 1:nc, unlist(strsplit(as.character(ss), ""))),
            nrow = n),
            2,
            paste0, collapse = "")
    })
}

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    mutate(tmp = str_split_n(var2)) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    group_by(var1) %>%
    mutate(n = paste0("new_var", 1:n())) %>%
    spread(n, tmp)
## A tibble: 4 x 7
## Groups:   var1 [4]
#   var1 var2                 new_var1 new_var2 new_var3 new_var4 new_var5
#  <int> <fct>                <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>
#1     1 abcdefghi            abcd     efgh     i        NA       NA
#2     2 abcdefghijklmnop     abcd     efgh     ijkl     mnop     NA
#3     3 abc                  abc      NA       NA       NA       NA
#4     4 abcdefghijklmnopqrst abcd     efgh     ijkl     mnop     qrst
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyr::separate` :

```
library(tidyr)
n <- ((max(nchar(df$var2)) - 1) %/% 4) + 1
df %>% separate(var2, into=paste0("new_var", seq(n)), sep=seq(n-1)*4, remove = FALSE)
#   var1                 var2 new_var1 new_var2 new_var3 new_var4 new_var5
# 1    1            abcdefghi     abcd     efgh        i                  
# 2    2     abcdefghijklmnop     abcd     efgh     ijkl     mnop         
# 3    3                  abc      abc                                    
# 4    4 abcdefghijklmnopqrst     abcd     efgh     ijkl     mnop     qrst
```

We first count how many groups we'll have using integer division, then we define new names on the fly and split at relevant positions using numeric values in the `sep` argument.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="var1  var2
1     abcdefghi 
2     abcdefghijklmnop
3     abc 
4     abcdefghijklmnopqrst",strin=F,h=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use successive `substr` on the same variable:

```r
  library(data.table)
  dff <- fread("var1  var2
1     abcdefghi 
2     abcdefghijklmnop
3     abc 
4     abcdefghijklmnopqrst")

  var2 <- dff[["var2"]]
  for (j in 1:5) {
    set(dff, j = paste0("new_var", j), value = substr(var2, 4*j - 3, 4*j))
  }
  dff
#>    var1                 var2 new_var1 new_var2 new_var3 new_var4 new_var5
#> 1:    1            abcdefghi     abcd     efgh        i                  
#> 2:    2     abcdefghijklmnop     abcd     efgh     ijkl     mnop         
#> 3:    3                  abc      abc                                    
#> 4:    4 abcdefghijklmnopqrst     abcd     efgh     ijkl     mnop     qrst
```

<sup>Created on 2018-08-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).</sup>