# Split by character quantity, create new columns with substrings Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I found this example on another post, but its for R, I need it for Python in a pandas dataframe

Original post = [Split string every n characters new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693267/split-string-every-n-characters-new-column)

Suppose I have a data frame like this with a string vector, var2

| var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abcdefghi |
| 2 | abcdefghijklmnop |
| 3 | abc |
| 4 | abcdefghijklmnopqrst |

What is the most efficient way to split var2 every n characters into new columns until the end of each string,

e.g if every 4 characters, the output would like look like this:

| var1 | var2 | new_var1 | new_var2 | new_var3 | new_var4 | new_var5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcdefghi | abcd | efgh | i |  |  |
| 2 | abcdefghijklmnop | abcd | efgh | ijkl | mnop |  |
| 3 | abc | abc |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | abcdefghijklmnopqrst | abcd | efgh | ijkl | mnop | qrst |

**To make it more difficult, I don't know how big is the longest string in column, but I need the total column to be as many as needed based on the resulting N columns**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
N = 4

# Custom function to split string
split_string = lambda x: pd.Series([x[i:i+N] for i in range(0, len(x), N)])

new_var = df['var2'].apply(split_string).fillna('')
new_var.columns = 'new_var' + (new_var.columns + 1).astype(str).str.zfill(3)

df = df.join(new_var)
```

Output:

| var1 | var2 | new_var001 | new_var002 | new_var003 | new_var004 | new_var005 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcdefghi | abcd | efgh | i |  |  |
| 2 | abcdefghijklmnop | abcd | efgh | ijkl | mnop |  |
| 3 | abc | abc |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | abcdefghijklmnopqrst | abcd | efgh | ijkl | mnop | qrst |

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. But why do you use ":i+4]" and later ", N)]". They should be both the same number right?

Comment: Just one extra thing, can you add leading zeroes to the (new_var.columns + 1)

Comment: 001, 002.....010, 011 etc

Comment: @RandomPerson. I updated my answer according to your comment. Can you check it please?

Comment: You're welcome. Glad this help you.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do all the preprocesssing within vanilla python, before returning to Pandas (it should be fast/efficient):

```py
outcome = [[ent[n:n+4] for n in range(0, len(ent), 4)] for ent in df.var2]
outcome = pd.DataFrame(outcome)
outcome.columns = outcome.columns.map(lambda col: f"new_var{col+1}")
pd.concat([df, outcome], axis="columns")

   var1                  var2 new_var1 new_var2 new_var3 new_var4 new_var5
0     1             abcdefghi     abcd     efgh        i     None     None
1     2      abcdefghijklmnop     abcd     efgh     ijkl     mnop     None
2     3                   abc      abc     None     None     None     None
3     4  abcdefghijklmnopqrst     abcd     efgh     ijkl     mnop     qrst
```