# Decode hex in R with NUL values

Tags: r, hex, decode

It is obvious that R doesn't alow nul characters:

```
c("abc\0d")
Error: nul character not allowed (line 1)
```

I'm trying to decode hex string and write results to a file. NUL values a crucial for me.
For now, i have written this much:

```
# Example of hex string
msg <- '504F03032C0000000803F8'
hex <- sapply(seq(1, nchar(as.character(msg)), by=2), 
              function(x) substr(msg, x, x+1))

# trying to decode hex
x <- NULL
for( i in 1:length(hex)){
  x[i] <- as.character(ifelse(hex[i] == "00", as.raw(0), rawToChar(as.raw(strtoi(hex[i], 16L)))))
}

write(paste0(x, collapse = ""), "test1")`
```

How could I change `as.raw(0)` part that in file i would see NUL value, not 00? Is it even possible to do so in R? Maybe I should change to other program, like python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to convert those values to character.  Why not keep them as numeric values, and use `writeBin` to write them out?  R has good support for that.  For example,

```
# Example of hex string
msg <- '504F03032C0000000803F8'

# Use solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2247574/2554330 to split
hex <- substring(msg, seq(1, nchar(msg), 2), seq(2, nchar(msg), 2))

# trying to decode hex
x <- strtoi(hex, 16)  # Converts to integer vector
writeBin(x, "test1", size=1)
```

Comment: FOR cycle didn't work while there was not "as.character". Your solution works like a charm! Thank you a lot!